# Is it best practice to display a percentage when the value is 0?

Tags: user-expectation, data

I have some data where I'm displaying the value, then I'm calculating the percentage and displaying it next to the original value. When the value is 0, it looks something like this

```
DataProperty1: 50 (50%)
DataProperty2: 0 (0%) //Percent value is showing even though it's 0
DataProperty3: 27 (27%)
```

Is it better to display the zero value percentage to keep the look consistent or can I remove the zero percentage and have something that looks like this instead?

```
DataProperty1: 50 (50%)
DataProperty2: 0        //Percent value is hidden
DataProperty3: 27 (27%)
```

Comment: Should extra attention be given to the 0 values? Does the 0 value signify the need for action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UX is about **consistency**.

If you want to show a percentage symbol against each of your values, you should also show it against zero.

After all, zero is a number too.

I haven't quite seen 0% being displayed before, since on Electronics, 0% generally means the device is shut down out of low power.

I wouldn't recommend hiding the percent symbol, since it will be confusing and the text might change alignment.

Comment: I agree - while 0 is 0 and doesn't need any sort of unit (as that doesn't change the value of 0) I think it is better to keep it consistent.